# HEX number conversion from program file

Tags: numbers, hex, number-formatting

I extracted a CAB file from a program file that I am trying to read. All numeric values are stored in a HEX format that I can't seem to deciphere. Here are some sample values and their actual value.

```
 x41200000 = 10
 x42c80000 = 100
 x43200000 = 160
 x437a0000 = 250
```

There must be some factor that I am not considering?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It was a HEX representation of a float. Thanks!